# OneWayToSource binding not working for UserControl DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, user-controls

(using VS 2010)

I have defined a `UserControl` with a `Curves` collection as a dependency property:

```
Public Class GroupedChartSetupControl
....
Public Shared ReadOnly CurvesProperty As DependencyProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("Curves", GetType(ObservableCollection(Of CurveVM)),   GetType(GroupedChartSetupControl), New UIPropertyMetadata(Nothing))

 Public Property Curves As ObservableCollection(Of CurveVM)
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(CurvesProperty), ObservableCollection(Of CurveVM))
    End Get
    Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of CurveVM))
        SetValue(CurvesProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
```

Then in the control's constructor, I initialize the Curve collection:

```
 Sub New()

    InitializeComponent()

    SetValue(CurvesProperty, New ObservableCollection(Of CurveVM))
    ....
```

Next, in a `Window` I'm placing this `UserControl` into the row template of a `datagrid`. I want to bind the `Curves` collection to the source property `SubCurves` in the `datagrid`'s `viewmodel`:

```
 <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <local:GroupedChartSetupControl Curves="{Binding SubCurves, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
....
```

Note the `OneWaytoSource` of the binding. The `UserControl` should be sending the `Curves` collection to the row's `ViewModel`, not the other way around. But when I debug, the `viewmodel` `SubCurves` property is always null. My WPF knowledge is fairly elementary, but I thought dependency properties were the way to go for exposing properties of a `UserControl`.

Comment: Do I? The actual `TestText` property is not ReadOnly. I thought the Shared (Static in C#) register line was supoosed to be ReadOnly.

Comment: Check output window for any binding errors. It seems binding is failing silently. In output window search for text `SubText`.

Comment: There are no errors in output, but in the control's constructor I removed what was apparently an unnecessary initialization of the `TestText` string and now things might be working. Dunno why that initialization was "wrong" though.

Comment: Okay I am now using `SetValue` to initialize the `Curves`, but still have same problem: `SubCurves` is null